# Injecting ejb into managed bean causes BeanInstantiationException

Tags: java, ejb, cdi

I've made a simple application to test this problem i'm having in small scale. I've got an ejb:

```
@Local
public interface PersonaDAO {
public void sayHello(Persona persona);
}


@Stateless
public class PersonaDAOImpl implements PersonaDAO {
    private PersonaDAOImpl() {
    }

    public void sayHello(String nombre) {
    System.out.println("HELLO " + nombre + " welcome to EJB 3!");
}
}
```

And i got a bean managing a jsf:

```
@ManagedBean(name="loginBean" )
@ViewScoped
public class LoginBean extends PageBean {
    private String nombre;
@EJB
private PersonaDAO dao; 

public String confirmar()
{
    String outcome = null;
    Persona persona = new Persona();
    persona.setNombre(nombre);
    dao.sayHello(persona);
    return outcome;
}
.....
}
```

I'm getting this deployment error:

```
DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfs:///home/shapacko/ambiente/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/Prueba.war" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve @EJB reference: [EJB Reference: beanInterface 'com.application.business.ServicioPersonasImpl', beanName 'null', mappedName 'null', lookupName 'null', owning unit 'AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@8203928{vfs:///home/shapacko/ambiente/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/Prueba.war}'] for environment entry: env/com.application.presentation.seguridad.LoginBean/sp in unit AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@8203928{vfs:///home/shapacko/ambiente/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/Prueba.war}
```

And then if i run the app i get a:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.ejb3.instantiator.spi.BeanInstantiationException: Could not create new instance with no arguments of: class com.application.persistence.PersonaDAOImpl
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:325)
```

I don't understand what's the problem. Is this injection possible? Or do i need to do a jndi lookup instead of injecting the ejb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that the use of the private constructor for the Stateless Session Bean is the cause of the issue, as evidenced by the following exception entry:

> org.jboss.ejb3.instantiator.spi.BeanInstantiationException: Could not create new instance with no arguments of: class com.application.persistence.PersonaDAOImpl

An exception of type `BeanInstantiationException` is typically thrown when the container is unable to create an instance of the bean. In all likelihood, this is due to the declaration of a private constructor, and the unavailability of any other non-private no-arg constructor in the Stateless Session Bean. It is inferred that you will have to change the visibility of `PersonaDAOImpl()` to public.

The EJB 3.1 specification states this quite explicitly:

> **4.9.2 Session Bean Class**
>
> - The class must be defined as public, must not be final, and must not be abstract. The class must be a top level class.
> - ***The class must have a public constructor that takes no parameters***. The container uses this constructor to create instances of the session bean class.
>     The following are the requirements for the session bean class: